# How to avoid unexpected argument warning using data classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-dataclasses

I have the following simple code.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Test:
    a: bool = True
    b: bool = True
    c: bool = True

    @classmethod
    def create_default(cls) -> 'Test':
        return cls(a=False, b=False, c=False)
```

I don't understand why PyCharm highlight the line:
`return cls(a=False, b=False, c=False)` with `unexpected argument`

Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: What version of Pycharm are you using? I'm on 2018.2.4 and I don't get said warning (and I believe I don't have anything disabled)

Comment: @DeepSpace 2017.3.3

Comment: Then try to update. It's probably a bug that has already been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Pycharm that has been already fixed. Update to the latest version (2018.2.4 when this answer was written)

Comment: I'm glad it's just a bug as it seems to have returned in version 2021.2.2.

Comment: Still here @ version 2021.3.2

Comment: Version 2023.2.3 says "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains tracks this regression again in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-59174/False-positive-unexpected-arguments-for-an-imported-pydantic-dataclass

The current workaround is to install the Pydantic plugin, which is officially listed under https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12861-pydantic.