# How to avoid "Unexpected argument" warning when creating new instance of data classes

Tags: python, pycharm, python-dataclasses

For the following code:

```py
@dataclass()
class Foo:
    x: float
    y: float

    @classmethod
    def origin_cls(cls):
        return cls(0., 0.)  # no warning
    
    def origin_self(self):
        return self.__class__(0., 0.)  # "Unexpected argument" warning
```

In PyCharm, `self.__class__(0., 0.)` was highlighted with a warning "Unexpected argument" for the method `origin_self`, while `cls(0., 0.)` works just fine with no warning. By the way, the class also method raised the same warning in a older version of PyCharm (mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276766/how-to-avoid-unexpected-argument-warning-using-data-classes)).

So how to avoid this "Unexpected argument" warning for `self.__class__` in dataclass? Is it a bug as well? Or am I doing something wrong and there is a way to fix it?

---

Additional info:

- PyCharm 2023.1
- Python 3.9

Comment: This is purely down to your IDE; the code works as written. However, there is **no good reason** to implement `origin_self`; a `classmethod` **will also work just the same** with an instance - looking up the class happens automatically. Of course, it's still *legal*, and should (and does) work as far as Python itself is concerned. Given the history, this should almost certainly be considered another bug in PyCharm - please instead ask about it on their issue tracker.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for pointing it out. The code is just a simplified demo. My original intention is to implement an `__add__` method to add two instances and return a new instance, and `classmethod` is by no means a viable solution. As for posting it on their issue tracker, I think I will do that :)

Comment: Is there a reason not to just write `Foo(0., 0.)`? *Inheriting from* dataclasses that overload an operator doesn't seem like a common use case....

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Like I said before, I intend to create an `__add__` method. If I have `foo1` and `foo2`, `foo_sum = foo1 + foo2` is what I want instead of `foo_sum = Foo(foo1.x+foo2.x, foo1.y+foo2.y)`. Or do you mean `Foo` should not be a dataclass in the first place?

Comment: I mean that, **when you implement** `__add__`, it should not be necessary to write `return self.__class__(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)`, but rather just `return Foo(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This `Foo` class has several subclasses that all use `__add__`, so `self.__class__()` should be the choice IMO.